# Are intersection of power set and power set of intersection equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $P(A) ∩ P(B) = P(A ∩ B)$?

At first glance it seems like its not true.

I tried writing out all the values of the power set using examples but I'm not sure on how to prove it.

Comment: It should be $P(A)P(B)$ instead of $P(A) \cap P(B)$.

Comment: And this is not always true. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then it is true.

Comment: @UrbanPENDU he's not using probability notation, he's denoting the power set

Comment: then why post it under probability-theory. It should be posted under set-theory.

Comment: Good question, I don't know the reason, but I know he's referring to power sets because he mentions them. @dave perhaps you should consider retagging?

Comment: thanks guys, edited to set theory

Comment: @UrbanPENDU More [tag:elementary-set-theory] tbh.

Answer (score 6):

$S \in P(A) \cap P(B)$ if and only if $S \in P(A)$ and $S \in P(B)$ if and only if $S \subset A$ and $S \subset B$ if and only if $S \subset A \cap B$ if and only if $S \in P(A \cap B)$.

Comment: just a little confused on this, can anyone explain in a bit of text. rather understand it than just remember the answer

Comment: @dave "if and only if" means "is equivalent to". The answer proves $S\in P(A)\cap P(B) \Leftrightarrow S \in P(A\cap B)$. This proves equality of the two sets.

Comment: @dave Translation: Things in $P(A)$ are subsets of $A$. Things in $P(B)$ are subsets of $B$ (this is by definition). If you're in $P(A) \cap P(B)$, then you must be a subset of $A$, and a subset of $B$. But if you're a subset of both $A$ and $B$, then you're a subset of $A \cap B$; that means you're a thing in $P(A \cap B)$! Note: here '!' means excitement

Comment: @dave : in addition to the above, I strongly urge you to justify things like this to yourself.  When you read something of the form "X if and only if Y", take it as a personal exercise; stop and try to prove that X implies Y and Y implies X.  In this case, the implications follow directly from the definitions of what things mean.